# Change page color of some documents

Tags: pdf, colors, document

I use Okular for handling my documents (pdf, epub, djvu) and one of the features I like is its ability to change page color to something that soothes your eye ( I generally set it moderate greyish instead of white).

However, there are some documents on which this feature doesnt work, even though those are just like other documents.

Can someone tell me why this is so, and what are the things I might be expecting ( like dpi or scanned / OCR options ) the next time i have the option of choosing the quality of document to choose from ?

Additionally, it would be perfect if I could perhaps add something or change something to make this feature work with my existing documents.

Thank You

(I can add a small snapshots of both documents, but only if its absolutely necessary.)

Edit :

I am including small portions of both types :
[image]

This is a page of a document which was clicked from a phone in the form of jpeg (and later converted by me).

[image]

This is a pdf on which this feature doesnt work.

Comment: I would say that it does not work when the PDF is only one full-page image per side. To change you have to extract all the images, provided with a new background and convert it back into a PDF.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand " one full-page image per side". Do you mean It has a page consisting of only image or  Do you mean the page is itself an image ?

Comment: One could say, the page itself is an image. Although this is technically not quite right.

Comment: And in fact, only 2 days back, I came across a bunch of jpegs taken from a smartphone camera. I was required to convert it to pdf. So all I did was bunch those images together and fed it to an online conversion tool. The page color feature did work on those as well, despite the fact that those images were taken pretty clumsily.

Comment: Like I said, it's a guess.

Comment: Maybe you could make a few examples.

Comment: You mean some snapshots of them ?

Comment: An example, with which it works, and an example with which it does not.

Comment: I've updated with pics.